# Mule ESB How to implement a counter variable to count how much times a flow is called

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-esb

I am wordering about how to implement a counter  which is will increase 1 step when flow is called. For example:
I have a flow named: http://localhost:8080/doSomething and a variable counter.
The counter variable will increase by 1 when I hit enter in doSomething service

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to store runtime data that is available across the application, you can store the data as objects in the Registry. 
Here is an example

To set the value

```
<scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
             <scripting:script engine="Groovy">                
                <![CDATA[muleContext.getRegistry().registerObject("Count", new Integer(14))]]>
              </scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

To read the value

```
<logger message="Count #[app.registry.get('Count')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a variable with integer value 1 in mule app registry in the starting of your flow as below:

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[#[app.registry.put('counter',1)]]]></expression-component>
```

To increment the value use:

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[#[app.registry.put('counter',app.registry['counter']+1)]]]></expression-component>
```

To retrieve final value of the counter flag, use the expression:

```
#[app.registry.get('counter')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a persistent storage solution. Variables in Mule do not live across invocations. Mule has a concept of Object Stores: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-object-stores

If you are a Mule Enterprise customer, analytics may be included in your subscription.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to collect statistics, then I suggest you to consider using [MuleSoft Insight](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/insight). You will be able to setup **Custom Business Events** in your flows and track important information. Finally, you can use **Insight Dashboard** on CloudHub to get appropriate stats by applying various filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can have object store in your flow which can store your counter(number of hits on to your flow) either in memory or in a persistent store. You can then retrieve the counter and increase it on subsequent hit to your flow.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/object-store-module-reference