# Mule until-successful syncronous retry does not capture the retry count

Tags: mule

Need help with synchronous retry until-successful.
I would like to keep a track of the retry count. 
For asynchronous calls there is a variable called process.attempt.count but for synchronous calls this variable does not work. 
Even if I use a variable to increment a count in session it defaults back to where it started as part of until-successful. 
Would really appreciate any help.

I have tried incrementing the counter inside until-successful but since there is no  variable propogation in mule in until-successful, variable defaults to original value

```
<until-successful failureExpression="#[sessionVars['code'] != 0]" maxRetries="6" secondsBetweenRetries="2" synchronous="true">
    <flow-ref name="Enquiryflow" />
</until-successful>

<sub-flow name="Enquiryflow">
      <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[sessionVars['retryCount']=='0']">
            <set-session-variable variableName="retryCount" value="#[sessionVars.retryCount + 1]"/>
            <flow-ref name="postRequestToXYS" />
            <flow-ref name="mapResponseTemplate" />
        </when>         
        <otherwise>            
            <flow-ref name="postRequestToABC" />
            <flow-ref name="mapResponseTemplate" />
        </otherwise>
      </choice>        
   </sub-flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to increment the counter. 
Mule says there is no variable propagation in until-successful retry mechanism.
This applies to session variable and variables.
However, we have an option called registry variables. Which to my surprise retained incremented counts though there is an exception.

Please follow this blog on how to use registry in mule.
[Mule ESB How to implement a counter variable to count how much times a flow is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993043/mule-esb-how-to-implement-a-counter-variable-to-count-how-much-times-a-flow-is-c/49994210#49994210)

Comment: There is no such thing as registry variables. You are really using the registry to store a value. This is unsafe with concurrent access, because it will cause undexpected results and probably it is a bad practice.